# my function entering to infinite loop when call AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The send_data function Called from createNewTable function(onclick).
i dont understand why my function entering to infinite loop when action_id === "new_table_btn"(action_id it's indicator ). Please help me

**HTML**

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick="createNewTable()">Send</button>
```

**JQuery/Ajax**

```
function createNewTable()
{
    _table_name = $("#table_name").val();
    var data = "Indicator=new_table&table_name=" + _table_name + "&player_email=" + player_email;
    send_data(data, "new_table_btn");
}


function send_data(j_data, action_id) {

    var results;
    //var k_data =  [{aaaa:"solange"}];
    $.ajax({
        url: "SrvController",
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'post',
        //contentType: 'application/json', 
        data: j_data, // "Indicator=world_games&player_email=dana@mmm.com", //"aaaa=lllll&aaa=pppp",//JSON.stringify(k_data),
        //processData: false,
        success: function (data, textStatus, jQxhr) {


            if (action_id === "join_table")
            {

                // turn_place =
                if (data["status"] === "success")
                {
                    player_place = data["sit"];
                    $("#playground").hide("slow", arguments.callee);
                    $("#startGame").show("slow");
                    if (!read_data)
                    {
                        new_round_data();
                        read_data = true;
                    }
                }

                else
                    $("#playground").append("fail");

            }
            if (action_id === "world_games")
            {
                read_activ_tables(data);
            }
            if (action_id === "new_round_data")
            {
                new_round(data);
            }
            if (action_id === "get_table_id")
            {
                _table_number = data["tableNumber"];
                var data = "Indicator=join_table&table_id=" + _table_number + "&player_email=" + player_email;
                send_data(data, "join_table");

            }
            if (action_id === "new_table_btn")
            {
                if (typeof data !== "undefined")
                    _table_number = data["tableId"];

                player_place = "1";
                $("#playground").hide("fast", arguments.callee);
                $("#startGame").show("slow");
                if (!read_data)
                {
                    read_data = true;
                    new_round_data();

                }

            }

        },
        error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
    //results.innerHTML = "processing...";
}
```

Comment: Try once with `type="button"` instead of `type="submit"`

Comment: what is error on console?

Comment: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: It looks like you're getting inside `new_table_btn` and once it's in there, have you checked if it keeps getting into `if (!read_data)` - because it could be calling `new_round_data();` and if it keeps getting there it'll just keep looping round in a circle